# NSwag creates JSON with random class names

Tags: c#, nswag

This code works - kind of.
It will create something that works.
But it uses class names like:
`Body1`, `Body2`, `Body3` and
`Response1`, `Response2`, `Response3`, `Response4`

I'm probably just missing a simple option, but I just can't figure out which one.

It works great if I use the GUI. But the GUI doesn't respect the JSON names and will insist on renaming them to UpperCamelCase

```
      var document = NSwag.OpenApiDocument.FromUrlAsync(url).Result;
      var settings = new NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp.CSharpClientGeneratorSettings
      {
        GenerateClientClasses = true,
        GenerateClientInterfaces = true,
        InjectHttpClient = true,
        DisposeHttpClient = true,
        GenerateExceptionClasses = true,
        ExceptionClass = "EdiException",
        WrapDtoExceptions = true,
        UseHttpClientCreationMethod = false,
        HttpClientType = "System.Net.Http.HttpClient",
        UseHttpRequestMessageCreationMethod = false,
        UseBaseUrl = true,
        GenerateBaseUrlProperty = true,
        GenerateSyncMethods =false,
        GeneratePrepareRequestAndProcessResponseAsAsyncMethods = false,
        ExposeJsonSerializerSettings = true,
        ClientClassAccessModifier = "public",
        ClassName = "CancellationService",

        CSharpGeneratorSettings =
        {
          TypeAccessModifier = "public",
          Namespace = "Edlund.NonLifeCore.Shared.DK.CancellationService",
          PropertyNameGenerator = UseNameGenerator,
          GenerateDataAnnotations = true,
          GenerateJsonMethods = true,
          GenerateDefaultValues = true,
          ClassStyle = NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp.CSharpClassStyle.Poco,
          JsonLibrary = NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp.CSharpJsonLibrary.NewtonsoftJson,
        }
      };

      var resolver = new NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp.CSharpTypeResolver(settings.CSharpGeneratorSettings);
      var generator = new NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp.CSharpClientGenerator(document, settings, resolver);
      var client = generator.GenerateFile();

      File.WriteAllLines(OutputPath + ".cs", new List<string> { client });
    }
  }

  public class CustomRespectSwaggerPropertyNameGenerator : IPropertyNameGenerator
  {
    /// <summary>Generates the property name.</summary>
    /// <param name="property">The property.</param>
    /// <returns>The new name.</returns>
    string IPropertyNameGenerator.Generate(JsonSchemaProperty property)
    {
      return property.Name.Replace('_', '-')
          .Replace("@", "")
          .Replace(".", "-");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TypeNameGenerator in the CSharpGeneratorSettings provided by NSwag.

I have solved the issue this way before. What you need to do is apply ToLowerInvariant to the first character of reference type names

```csharp
var settings = new NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp.CSharpClientGeneratorSettings
{

  // ...

  CSharpGeneratorSettings =
    {
      // ...
      TypeNameGenerator = new CamelCaseTypeNameGenerator()
    }
};

// ...

public class CamelCaseTypeNameGenerator : ITypeNameGenerator
{
  public string Generate(JsonSchema schema, string? typeNameHint, IEnumerable<string> reservedTypeNames)
  {
    if (typeNameHint == null || typeNameHint.Length == 0)
    {
      return typeNameHint ?? "DefaultTypeName";
    }

    return char.ToLowerInvariant(typeNameHint[0]) + typeNameHint.Substring(1);
  }
}

// ...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I added a bit more detail. Thanks for feedback.